# How to activate ZLE (ZSH Line Editor)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

How do I activate ZLE, the ZSH line editor?

I am trying to enable the local history in ZSH. I've added `zle set-local-history 1` to my `~/.zshrc`, but it prints the error: `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active`.

I can confirm the behavior with `zle widget`: `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active`.

Looking at `man zshzle` I see many examples what will happen if zle is active. However, *I find zero information on how I can activate zle*. Thus the question: Can someone please tell me, how I activate ZLE?

Comment: "The zsh line editor is usually abbreviated to `zle'. Normally it fires itself up for any interative shell; you don't have to do anything special until you decide you need to change its behaviour. If everything looks OK and you're not interested in how zle is started up, skip to the next subsection. " please read [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide04.html) for more info

Comment: Already did. No info there on how to activate it.

Comment: _zle_ is getting active automatically when you are typing at the interactive shell prompt. All your input is handled by _zle_, no need to activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Zsh Line Editor* (or ZLE for short) is to the Z Shell what `readline` is to Bash: It’s what you use automatically when entering/editing your command line. Hence, when Zsh sources your `.zshrc` file, the ZLE is not active, since you are not on the command line yet. The ZLE is not active either after you submit your command line and does not become active again until you return to the command line.

To use `set-local-history`, you need to bind it to a key or to a hook. For example:

```bash
autoload -Uz add-zle-hook-widget

() {
  $1() {
    zle set-local-history 1
    show-zle-state
  }

  # Create a widget that calls the function above.
  zle -N $1

  # Start each new cmd line in local history mode.
  add-zle-hook-widget line-init $1

  # Press Ctrl-X plus L to enable local history mode.
  bindkey '^Xl' $1
} use-local-history

() {
  $1() {
    zle set-local-history 0
    show-zle-state
  }

  # Create a widget that calls the function above.
  zle -N $1

  # Press Ctrl-X plus G to enable global history mode.
  bindkey '^Xg' $1
} use-global-history

# Prints the current zle state below the cmd line. 
show-zle-state() {
  zle -M $ZLE_STATE
}
```

Comment: How do you explain that I executing `zle set-local-history 1` on the command line returns the same error? Shouldn't ZLE be active by that time?

Comment: When you type that on the command line and then press Enter, the command you entered does not run on the command line. Rather, Enter submits the text you entered on the command line, after which the command line is no longer active. The shell tries to parse and execute the text you entered. Only after the parsed command has been executed (or the shell fails to parse) is control returned to the command line and ZLE becomes active.

Comment: Yes! Finally I get it, this makes lots of sense. I have adopted another solution to add it to my script from https://github.com/cosmicexplorer/.zsh/blob/master/.zshrc.

But it is your comment, that finally made me understand what "is active" means in this context. Thank you!